# Black texture blinking using QQuickImageProvider

Tags: qt, qtquick3d

I'm using QQuickImageProvider to pass 3d scanner images from C++ to QML and then use these images as customer texture for model (using qt quick 3d here). I faced a problem that texture blinks getting to black for a second. It repeats quite often.
I used to investigate streaming images as VideoOutput but this approach doesn't suit me as I have to use geometry data of surface and in case of VideoOutput it doesn't allow to map these images on geometry coordinates. Could you advise something in this case?
Below is example of my code.

**QML:**

```
Image {
   id: textureImage
   source: renderControl.sourceUrl
   anchors.fill: parent
   visible: false // tried with cache true and false both
                }
 Node {
   id: mainScene
   DirectionalLight {
       position: Qt.vector3d(-500, 500, -100)
       ambientColor: Qt.rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)
   }
   Model {
       id: viewModel
       position: Qt.vector3d(0, 50, 0)
       visible: true
       scale: Qt.vector3d(10, 11, 4)

       geometry:  RenderData{ // C++ class which sends url to image provider
              id: renderControl
              objectName: "geometryData"
              }

              DefaultMaterial {
                id: defaultMaterial
                Texture {
                   id: baseColorMap
                   sourceItem: textureImage
                }
                cullMode: DefaultMaterial.NoCulling
                diffuseMap: baseColorMap
                }

                materials: [
                   defaultMaterial
                ]
              }
```

**C++**

.h

```
class TextureImageProvider : public QObject, public QQuickImageProvider
{
  QImage requestImage(const QString& id, QSize* size, const QSize& requestedSize) override;
 Q_SIGNALS:
  void imageUpdated(const QUrl& imageUrl);
 std::shared_ptr<QImage> textureImage_;  
}

class RenderData : public QQuick3DGeometry
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QUrl sourceUrl READ sourceUrl WRITE setSourceUrl NOTIFY sourceUrlChanged)
        TextureImageProvider* imageProvider_;   

}
```

.cpp

```
void RenderData::updateData(QImage& textureImage)
{
const QUrl imageUrl = QString("image://texture_image_provider/%1").arg(Uuid::createUuid().toString().c_str());
   textureImage_ = std::make_shared<QImage>(image);
   Q_EMIT imageUpdated(url);
}

QImage TextureImageProvider::requestImage(const QString& id, QSize* size, const QSize& requestedSize)
{
    return *textureImage_;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
   engine_->addImageProvider("texture_image_provider", &renderData_-getImageProvider());
}
```

Comment: please provide  a [mre]

Comment: I've just updated code block above